# How can I test whether an int is included in IntDef definition

Tags: android

Take the following example.

### Error message

> Must be one of: DownloadRequest.STATUS_UNKNOWN,
>   DownloadRequest.STATUS_DOWNLOADING, DownloadRequest.STATUS_COMPLETE,
>   DownloadRequest.STATUS_PAUSED, DownloadRequest.STATUS_CANCELLED,
>   DownloadRequest.STATUS_TEMP_PAUSED, DownloadRequest.STATUS_QUEUED

### Query database

The data is pulled from the database with a `Cursor` and put into my custom class.

```
request.setStatus(cursor.getInt(COLUMN_STATUS));
```

### Set custom builder

This custom class method takes an integer and sets its internal status. The integer is validated by an [IntDef](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/IntDef.html) annotation.

```
@NonNull
public Builder setStatus(@StatusEnum int status) {
    mInstance.mStatus = status;
    return this;
}
```

### The IntDef annotation

```
@IntDef({STATUS_UNKNOWN, STATUS_DOWNLOADING, STATUS_COMPLETE, STATUS_PAUSED, STATUS_CANCELLED, STATUS_TEMP_PAUSED, STATUS_QUEUED})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface StatusEnum {}
```

### The issue

The only values that enter the database are values given by the `StatusEnum` annotation. This is validated at all steps. I would still validate the information coming from the database.

How can I test whether an integer exists in an IntDef definition. I could test that given integer is one of the constants. However, that will increase future code maintenence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't look at the values of `@IntDef` because as you can see in the source code [[1]](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/marshmallow-mr2-release/annotations/src/android/support/annotation/IntDef.java) of the annotation:

```
@Retention(SOURCE)
@Target({ANNOTATION_TYPE})
public @interface IntDef {
    /** Defines the allowed constants for this element */
    long[] value() default {};

    /** Defines whether the constants can be used as a flag, or just as an enum (the default) */
    boolean flag() default false;
}
```

it is marked with [SOURCE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html#SOURCE) as `RetentionPolicy`:

> **SOURCE**
>   Annotations are to be discarded by the compiler.

For this reason you can't iterate at runtime.